# Spacing in a multi-lettered subscript word is too large

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, kerning

I'm a new user of Latex and still trying to figure it out. Currently I have a problem where if I want to have a subscript which contains more than one letter, the spacing between the letters is too large. Namely, writing `$\hat{\tau}_{eff}$` results in:

[image: effective time constant estimate]

What would be the best way to bring "eff" closer together?

Comment: I think, `eff` should be in text mode, not in math mode, so `\hat{\tau}_{\text{eff}}` (requires `amsmath` or `mathtools` package )

Comment: It definitely helps, but then I loose the nice italic effect. I can add it though with `$\hat{\tau}_{\text{\textit{eff}}}$`. Do you know what is the best practice when it comes to subscripts?

Comment: Use `\mathit{eff}` instead

Comment: `_{\textit{eff}}` is enough. However, I would not recommend it, as it is a bit confusional with italic variables in formulae.

Comment: _never_ use math italic for multi-letter words, whether or not in subscript, use `_{\mathit{eff}}`

Comment: @David Carlisle:??? Your last comment seems self-contradictory, or do I not understand what you mean?

Comment: The whole point of the design of the default math italic font is to make adjacent letters clearly not parts of a word, but look like a product of variables. `\mathit` is the test italic font, for use in math mode, which is designed for words.

Comment: @Bernard `\mathit` does not select math italic, it selects text italic, in math, (and `\textit` by default will not get smaller in subscripts so it less useful here)

Comment: `\mathit{eff}` solves both the kerning and italic issues. Thank you!

By the way, since I'm also relatively new when it comes to questions and commenting on Stack Exchange, how do I mark a comment as correct answer?

Comment: @MarkoF: Comments are comments and no 'markable' answer, but I agree with David Carlisle: Don't use math italic for multiletter words. Subscripts should be not italic, in my point of view

Comment: @David Carlisle: When I use it, \textit in a subscript does get smaller.

Comment: @Bernard you most likely have amsmath loaded

Comment: Yes, or mathtools. Doesn't everyone use it?

Comment: I meant `multiletter subscripts shouldn't be used with italic font` (the comment above is too old to edit and I am too lazy to copy again ;-))

Answer (score 2):

Christian Hupfer and David Carlisle pointed out that `_{\mathit{eff}}` command is the correct answer. It solves both the kerning issue and keep the word in italic.